# Accessing jquery validation variables in Typescript class

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-validate, aurelia

currently I'm facing the following problem where I hope that someone can help me:

I'm developing a aurelia-cli application using TypeScript. The aurelia-validation is in my opinion not that good and much too complex. So I'm using jQuery-Validation.

I have the following class:

```
export class RegistrationForm{
    @bindable errors: string[];

    public attached(){
        let validator = $("#registration-form").validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                this.errors.push(error.text());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the following template:

```
<template>
  ...
  <ul if.bind="errors">
     <li repeat.for="error of errors">
         ${error}
     </li>
  </ul>
...
</template>
```

I know, that the stated example with `this.errors.push(error.text())` is wrong because on that point I don't have access to the class variable `errors`.

Now my question is, if there is a possibility to transfer the `error.text()` information to the class variable so that the texts get listed in frontend?

My target is, that each time when the user changes fields (onfocusout) the respective field gets validated and a message is displayed on the top of the page. The display should work with the aurelia-binding.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `function()` to [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `=>`, as they preserve the scope in which they're declared, and therefore `this` refers to the class instead of the function.

```
export class RegistrationForm{
    @bindable errors: string[];

    public attached(){
        let validator = $("#registration-form").validate({
            onfocusout: (element) => {
                $(element).valid();
            },
            errorPlacement: (error, element) => {
                this.errors.push(error.text());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, the arrow function doesn't necessarily refer to the class. It actually refers to the scope in which it's declared. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20foo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20logName%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(this.name)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20logName()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo.bind(%7B%20name%3A%20%22bob%22%20%7D)()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D